# Plaseholderapi не работает

Tags: java, minecraft

Я создал два сервера и обьеденил их спомощью bunge и установил на него плагин tablistplus и placeholderapi
но при запуске вылазит ошибка

```
 Error loading plugin PlaceholderAPI
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.findClass(PluginClassloader.java:152)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass0(PluginClassloader.java:66)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass(PluginClassloader.java:59)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugin(PluginManager.java:340)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:250)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:271)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:67)
    at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass0(PluginClassloader.java:103)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass(PluginClassloader.java:59)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 13 more
```

также установлен плагин autoreconnect и сами сервера на версии 1.18.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плагин placeholderapi не является плагином для bungecord. Это плагин для сервера.